# how to use @XmlElement in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to learn how to store objects as XML files in java, but I'm having a bit of a problem.

Most tutorials that I have found have said that I should use the @XmlElement annotation with set methods, however is there another way to use them, as my objects would be easier to make using just the constructors I have for them instead of a set for each field.

Answer (score 2):

The `@XmlElement` can also be used on the property. You will find more information in the [javadoc](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html).

The javadoc gives this example:

```
public class USPrice {
    @XmlElement(name="itemprice")
    public java.math.BigDecimal price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All public fields and properties (get/set method pairs) will be treated by default as if they were annotated with `@XmlElement`.  You can add `@XmlElement` on the get or set method.  You can also annotate the field (instance variable).  If you do you should annotate your class with `@XmlAccesorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

JAXB does not currently support annotating constructors.  If you are dealing with immutable objects then the following may help:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html